# Change default behaviour of date picker

Tags: date-and-time

Is there any way to change the date picker of OnePlus 3t. I can only traverse only through months. imagine setting dob for a 30+ yr old guy.

[image: date picker image]

Android 8.0
Oxygen OS 5.0.2

Comment: Touch on year on top left of your screen to navigate year wise,
in your case please touch 2001 above sat.

Comment: Please post as answer. I touched everything except that. I didn't notice it before. May be because it's grayed out meaning disabled.

Comment: actually I'm developer and I also don't prefer this date picker as android didn't provide it as user friendly, I always prefer HOLO theme scroll picker, because client always complains on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just click on the year (showing on the top eg - 2001) then you can change the year It will show list of years like this:

[image]

Comment: can this be set as the initial state programatically ??

Comment: You can set this to desired date,month,year programmatically by setting the parameters in constructor on DatePickerDialog look here, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog#DatePickerDialog(android.content.Context,%20android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,%20int,%20int,%20int)